# Should I convert my whole project to typescript if i want to use one typescript component? React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

My project was made on Expo blank space mode, I want to add a calendar and the package i'll be using is written in Typescript, can I use it without converting the whole project into typescript?

Comment: Typescript can run regular js because it's a subset of it. Therefore if you wanted you can run all of your js code in a ts project. I know this isn't the answer to your question but I figured it's worth mentioning

Comment: So converting my whole project won't affect the code? I wouldn't be in need to change any code?

Comment: Yea checkout this article from fcc https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-typescript-to-a-javascript-project/

Comment: Does the package provide a compiled version? If it's not, you can also use typescript only to compile the calendar package down to javascript